# ERROR java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-sqlite

I'm working on *Android Studio Project* for my university (app calendar and more), and one of the functionalities is touch in a day of a calendar (`CalendarView`), display a layout for add event and later the event is saved in a `SQLITE`, (in another activity is where the list of events is displayed) the problem is when I want to delete an event (`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5`).
In Viewevents eliminar(`String dato`) is the code with error, How do I fix the issue? Thanks.

View events:

```
public class ViewEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {
//al mantener la wea apretada
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_events);

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ltvListaEventos);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    int dia,mes,anio;
    dia=mes=anio=0;

    dia=bundle.getInt("dia");
    mes=bundle.getInt("mes");
    anio=bundle.getInt("anio");
    String cadena= dia+" - "+ mes + " - "+ anio;

    BDSQLite bd= new BDSQLite(getApplicationContext(), "eventos", null,1);
    db= bd.getReadableDatabase();

    String sql="select * from eventos where fechadesde='"+cadena+"'";
    Cursor c;



    String nombre,fechadesde,horadesde,fechahasta,horahasta,descripcion,ubicacion;
    try {
        c=db.rawQuery(sql,null);
        arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        if(c==null||c.getCount()==0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No hay eventos disponibles", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                nombre=c.getString(1);
                ubicacion=c.getString(2);
                fechadesde=c.getString(3);
                horadesde=c.getString(4);
                fechahasta=c.getString(5);
                horahasta=c.getString(6);
                descripcion=c.getString(7);
                arrayAdapter.add(nombre+", "+ubicacion+", "+fechadesde+", "+horadesde+", "+fechahasta+", "+horahasta+", "+descripcion);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Error: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();

    }


}



private  void  eliminar(String dato){
    String []datos= dato.split(", ");

    String sql="delete from eventos where nombreEvento='"+datos[0]+"' and" +
            " ubicacion='"+datos[1]+"' and fechadesde='"+datos[2]+"' and " +
            "horadesde='"+datos[3]+"' and fechahasta='"+datos[4]+"' and horahasta='"+datos[5]+"' and descripcion='"+datos[6];
    try {

        arrayAdapter.remove(dato);         //eliminar del menú
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        db.execSQL(sql);


        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Evento eliminado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error:"+ ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CharSequence []items= new CharSequence[2];
    items[0]="Eliminar Evento";
    items[1]="Cancelar";
    builder.setTitle("Eliminar evento")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    if(i==0){
                        //eliminar evento
                        eliminar(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                    }
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog= builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    return false;
}
```

}

BDSQlite:

```
public class BDSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private String sql = "create table eventos(" +
        "idEvento int identity,"+
        "nombreEvento varchar(40)," +
        "ubicacion varchar(60)," +
        "fechadesde date,"+
        "horadesde time,"+
        "fechahasta date,"+
        "horahasta time," +
        "descripcion varchar(60))";
```

Add event activity

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


private EditText nombreEvento, ubicacion, fechadesde, horadesde, fechahasta, horahasta;
private EditText descripcion;

private Button guardar, cancelar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    nombreEvento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNombreEvento);
    ubicacion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtUbicacion);
    fechadesde = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaDesde);
    fechahasta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtFechaHasta);
    horadesde = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHorainicio);
    horahasta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHoraHasta);
    descripcion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescripcion);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int dia = 0, mes = 0, anio = 0;

    dia=bundle.getInt("dia");
    mes=bundle.getInt("mes");
    anio=bundle.getInt("anio");


    fechadesde.setText(dia + " - " + mes + " - " + anio);
    fechahasta.setText(dia + " - " + mes + " - " + anio);

    guardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnguardar);
    cancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancelar);
    guardar.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancelar.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == guardar.getId()) {
        //guardar datos cajas de texto
        BDSQLite bd = new BDSQLite(getApplication(), "eventos", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase db = bd.getWritableDatabase();



        String sql = "insert into eventos" +
                "(nombreEvento, ubicacion, fechadesde, horadesde, fechahasta, horahasta," +
                "descripcion) values('" +
                nombreEvento.getText()+
                "','"+ ubicacion.getText()+
                "','" +fechadesde.getText()+
                "','" + horadesde.getText()+
                "','"+fechahasta.getText()+
                "','"+horahasta.getText()+
                "','"+descripcion.getText();
        try {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            nombreEvento.setText("");
            ubicacion.setText("");
            fechadesde.setText("");
            fechahasta.setText("");
            horadesde.setText("");
            horahasta.setText("");
            descripcion.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Evento guardado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    } else {
        this.finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

}

ERROR:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
at com.example.niikoo.fondocelular.ViewEventsActivity.eliminar(ViewEventsActivity.java:87)
at com.example.niikoo.fondocelular.ViewEventsActivity.access$000(ViewEventsActivity.java:17)
at com.example.niikoo.fondocelular.ViewEventsActivity$1.onClick(ViewEventsActivity.java:116)
```

EDIT: The code with the structure of sql and datos, how i fix the error:(

Comment: what is the length of **`datos`**

Comment: As the error suggest you are trying to use array element that doesn't exist i.e
the array is out of bounds check dato[6] if it exist or not

Comment: As error  indicates you have array of size 5.. It means you can only get data from index 0 to 4 from that array.. anything above that will throw ArrayOutofBoundsExcetion..

Comment: Is defined in sql i think, i dont know how to fix the issue:/

Comment: I know, but i dont know how to fix the issue, the code have all the information about how is created the method:(

Comment: Please add the stack trace to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception line `(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5)` clearly mentions that you are Trying to get `index=5`but the length of the `dato` is `5`(`length=5`).

So, use only proper index i.e. index `0 to 4`. **OR** Make sure that enough `indexes` exists to access.

**Note:** You have used `dato.split(", ");`. Try with `dato.split(",");`. May be the problem is with pattern of splitter.

Comment: In the last edit i put the structure, in ArrayAdapter.add i put the sentences separated by ",", how i fix the error:(, i posted all the code only eliminar(String dato), have error

Comment: If i change to (","), this appear in  AVD, PS: how i see the text present in dato?


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Crhc.jpg

Comment: I fix the SQL-Query, and the error is still appearing :(, how i see the text in datos??

Comment: @NicolasOporto Are you sure that same code is updated here. Because there are enough chances of _typo_

Comment: so, what i do?:(

Comment: But, how i find the latest code?, i find the code in a Youtube class:(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `String dato` which you are splitting by commas to an array may not be the length that you think.  The error is showing 5 items in the array, so the greatest index you can access in that case would be `datos[4]` since arrays are 0-based.

Debug your array after you split:

```
String []datos= dato.split(", ");
```

Comment: I dont know why are 5 elements and why exist the error, in the last edit i put the code correctly, if you can tell me how to fix the issue :( thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the input of this method, it's not in the code.

```
eliminar(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
```

The error you get occurs because the array you get after splitting the String has only 5 elements (4 commas):

```
private  void  eliminar(String dato) {
    String []datos= dato.split(", ");
    ...
```

But then you try to get the 6th (index 5) and 7th (index 6) elements from that array:

```
datos[5]+"' and descripcion='"+datos[6];
```

There are no such elements, therefore you get this `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

To fix, try to find the input of your **adapterView**.

EDIT: In this line **2 Strings appear to be empty**:

```
arrayAdapter.add(nombre+", "+ubicacion+", "+fechadesde+", "+horadesde+", "+fechahasta+", "+horahasta+", "+descripcion);
```

Hence, when you get a ", , " and split it with split(", ") it doesn't count the "" String and you get less items in the resulting array, which leads to the error.

Comment: The input is in Viewevents arrayAdapter.add, please help

Comment: I know, how i see the text inside datos?, or see the elements that are not showing in array?? thanks

Comment: Just debug the application, use LogCat to see which items are empty and track them to find the origin of the problem. I told you all I could tell.